# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Buffer;

Tags: retrofit

when i use retrofit .I got the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Buffer;i use okhttpclient in order to set header for retrofit.get userList is a post method,and i need to send body in request.

```
private void getUserList(int startIndex){
    final JSONObject audienceObj = ProtocolHelper.getProtocolUtils(mContext).getUserlistJsonObj(mRoomData.mUid, mRoomData.mRoomId, startIndex);
    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(
        new Interceptor() {
          @Override
          public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("sessionId", CommonData.getUserInfo(mContext).sessionId);
                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        })
    .build();


    String baseUrl = ProtocolUtils.BASE_URL+"/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okClient)
    .build();

    String audienceUrl = ProtocolHelper.getProtocolUtils(mContext).getProtocolUrl(ProtocolUtils.PROTOCOL_MSG_ID_MEMBER_LIST);
    AudienceInterface audienceInterface = retrofit.create(AudienceInterface.class);
    Call<String> call = audienceInterface.getAudienceList(audienceUrl,audienceObj);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure"+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public interface AudienceInterface {

@POST("{url}")
Call<String>getAudienceList(@Path("url") String url,@Body JSONObject boder);
```

}

the log t.getMessage is :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Buffer;

Comment: Started getting this error when upgraded to Retrofit 2.5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright.~I found this error last time too.
By this:
**NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Buffer**
You might lost another jar lib--**Okio**.
You can download the jar file from github:
https://github.com/square/okio
And add this lib to your project.

Answer (score 9):

I solved it by adding:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:2.1.0'
```

in dependencies under build.gradle(Module: app).